# iOS Photos referencing the same photo on different iOS devices

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

I am making an app using photos of customer items. I would like to use Apple "Photos" (and its API) to handle the photo synchronising, etc. and not just save the photos to disk as files.
If I save a photo to Photos, I can reference it locally by using the "localIdentifier" like this:

```
let customerAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(custAssetsCollection, options: nil)
let localId = (customerAssets.firstObject as? PHAsset)?.localIdentifier
let img = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers([localId!], options: nil)
```

And you can also get the localIdentifier when saving the image like this:

```
let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(image)
plh = request.placeholderForCreatedAsset!
let localId = plh.localIdentifier
```

This works very fine on ONE devise. However, If I want to acces the exact same photo on an other device (using the same apple-ID of course), it is impossible as the localIdentifier is just that: local. 
I can make a collection and name it and then use that collection to get the photo, but that means I have to have an album for each customer?
Also I have NOT found a way to give an image a name, when saving it to Photos.
Apart from that the Photos API has so many cool features, that is a shame not to use it? I get background synchronisation and editing options for free.
Any bright ideas or should I just settle with one album per customer? Or have anybody some good ideas how to share photos across devices

Comment: I have same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: No I ended up with one album per customer, until I refactored it to file a blob storage